# Videos in Components not loading every time

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I have a component that has a video inside of it.. it loads no problem when you first visit the page but then when you go back to the page it doesn't load again...

After checking the network analyser in chrome dev tools show that its status is pending... For the moment a CDN is not possible for the content, regardless Im not sure it would solve the issue.

I am very curious to hear if anyone has any experience with the new angular and this kind of issue

UPDATE ----

This is an issue with Chrome browser and how it loads assets.

Using this in the destroy method seems to get some extra mileage and by that i mean I can go between the page and other pages 3 times now but then the videos dont display.. definitely a chrome bug, hopefully as angular and chrome are made by the same folks maybe they will come up with some fix.. for the moment this looks like its gonna have to do :

```
 ngOnDestroy() {
        jQuery('video').each(function() {
            jQuery(this)[0].pause();
            jQuery(jQuery(this)[0]).attr('src', "");
            jQuery(this)[0].load();
            jQuery(this)[0].remove();
        });
}
```

Comment: How are you loading the video? HTML 5 video tag?

Comment: Can you reproduce in a Plunker?

Comment: I cant at present, I am using a javascript library called seriously.js - basically there is a html  video element on the page and seriously takes it and creates a canvas element with it.. it works the first time you visit the page but when you go back to it sometimes it works a second time but then it doesnt again... in dev tools it shows as pending and after a few minutes it comes back again

Comment: This appears to be an issue with chrome and SPA's - still looks like there is no fix for this http://www.unknownerror.org/opensource/foreverjs/forever/q/stackoverflow/16137381/html5-video-element-request-stay-pending-forever-on-chrome

Comment: updated answer with temporary fix..